# Spree integration with ebs payment gateway

Tags: payment-gateway, spree

I'm using spree 0.70.1 and want to integrate it with ebs payment gateway. There is an extension 
https://github.com/pronix/spree-ebsin but it throws an error while installing

```
 spree_ebsin at /Users/dhirengupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318@store/bundler/gems/spree-           ebsin-a323630d78d1 did not have a valid gemspec.

 This prevents bundler from installing bins or native extensions, but that may not affect  its functionality.
 The validation message from Rubygems was:
 authors may not be empty
```

Please help me to integrate spree with ebs. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

thats not really an error and wont stop you using the gem. The gemspec needs to be updated as it does not have this:

```
  s.author            = 'John Dyer'
  s.email             = 'john@spreecommerce.com'
  s.homepage          = 'http://www.spreecommerce.com'
```

Comment: how can i use this gem for spree 0.11.x ?